# How to properly populate Docker Django image with data from Postgres?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I wanted to create a Docker image for my Django project called mysite that has two apps tracks and users. I used `docker build -t mysite` to build my docker image. I have written a Dockerfile like it says on dockerhub. Then I created **docker-compose.yml** file and bash script **entypoint.sh** that I use in docker-compose file.

These are my files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM django:onbuild

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:   
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    container_name: postgres_container
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
     - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
     - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings_docker
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/10/main   
  web:
    image: mysite:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: mysite_container
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings_docker
```

entrypoint.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh

    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
    python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    exec "$@"
```

So when I wanted to start the whole container I used following commands

```
docker build .
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

My database in settings.py is

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'postgres',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
}
```

My database in settings_docker.py, that I use in container is

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'postgres',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
            'HOST': 'db',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
}
```

Then I added new **settings_docker.py** where I set my host to 'db' (In original settings.py I have `HOST='localhost'` and when I start the Django app with `python manage.py runserver` I have all my tables and relations froPostgreses database) file and added environment variable `DOCKER_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settins_docker` to my web service in docker-compose.yml and the container starts properly, but now I don't have my database relations and tables.

So, how can I migrate those relations to docker? Which is the right way to populate my docker container with relations from postgres? I have tried with volumes in **docker-compose.yml** where I specified my postgres data file (my data is in `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main`) but it's still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you consider switching to another approach - a native and quite portable* solution for providing an initial state of a DB would be to utilize Django [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/howto/initial-data/). Utilizing that method, you have to bring your DB state into an expected state, meaning to provide initial tables and records. When ready, perform:

```
python manage.py dumpdata
```

In order to store the data in a file. Then, reuse the saved file with:

```
python manage.py loaddata fixturename
```

Another, but less flexible, way would be to provide `.sql` file to a init-db location - read in the manual where that is depending specifically on your Postgres version.

*portable, meaning you can maneuver with the file, send it, edit it and easily apply it.

Comment: Thank you! This seems a good solution to me. Should I then use these two commands in my bash script entrypoint.sh?

Comment: I'd rather suggest using it manually to always know exactly whats in your DB. But yes, you can put it in your entrypoint - although this can cause your DB state to be altered if you persist your DB somewhere and rerun your app (with a DB already populated). On production envs it should be done manually.

Comment: I tried that but it seems that my data is not copied. If I do it outside the container it works, but not inside. Should I try with pg_dump?

Comment: Do you get any error while `loaddata`? could you paste the actual command you are throwing at it? You might go with `pg_dump` but would that mean you'd have your own postgres image where you'd have copied the pg_dump?